# How can I insert the current git commit into an org-mode buffer to be evaluated on export?

Tags: git, export, elisp, org-mode

```
#+Author: A. U. Thor
#+Date: [2014-01-06 Mon]
#+MACRO: version 2.1

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :exports none :tangle no
  (substring (shell-command-to-string "git rev-parse --short HEAD") 0 -1)
#+END_SRC

This document interacts with version {{{version}}} of the
StackExchange API and is maintained by {{{author}}}.  It was last
modified at {{{modification-time(%Y-%m-%dT%T%z)}}} (commit ??).  This
copy was exported on {{{time(%Y-%m-%dT%T%z)}}}.
```

produces

```
                              ____________

                                  TEST

                               A. U. Thor
                              ____________


                            [2014-01-06 Mon]


Table of Contents
_________________




This document interacts with version 2.1 of the StackExchange API and is
maintained by A. U. Thor.  It was last modified at
2014-01-06T20:32:14-0500 (commit ??).  This copy was exported on
2014-01-06T20:32:16-0500.
```

How can I insert the current commit (as returned by the tiny bit of elisp) into the `??`?
I supposedly discovered a way to do it, but it is ineffective in normal export and probably only works during tangling.

Comment: Would solving this in git instead of emacs be an option? If so, you could look into filter-based keyword expansion: http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-2.html#Keyword-Expansion

Comment: @Carsten If it can be coerced into an org macro (or anything that will remove the `Id:` artifact), that would be more than fine. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add a name to the code block, then you can call that block code from somewhere else:

```
#+NAME: commit
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :exports none :tangle no
  (substring (shell-command-to-string "git rev-parse --short HEAD") 0 -1)
#+END_SRC

This corresponds to git commit call_commit().
```

The output I get when exporting:

> This corresponds to git commit `2464d0a'.

This is documented [in the org-mode manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Evaluating-code-blocks.html#Evaluating-code-blocks) for source code block evaluation.